# Visual Studio multibyte chars to single bytes

Tags: c++, mfc, char, google-contacts-api, multibyte

Is there a simple way to convert multibyte UTF8 data (from Google Contacts API via https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/) to single bytes? I know the extended ASCII set is non-standard but, for example, my program which will display the info in an MFC CListBox is quite happy to show 'E acute' as 0xE9. I only need it to cope with a few similar European symbols. I've discovered I can convert everything with MultiByteToWideChar() but don't want to have to change lots of functions to accept wide characters if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want UTF8 to ANSI?

Comment: I suppose you could do a MultiByteToWideChar and then WideCharToMultiByte with the codepage parameter set accordingly. YMMV and those european symbols you speak of might not render the same way in every locale of Windows.  Going all in with unicode (wide-char) will generate more consistent results.

Comment: MBCS support for MFC is being phased out. Visual Studio 2013 doesn't come with MBCS support for MFC anymore (although there is a separate download). Better change your code to use Unicode while there is still time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to convert `char *` from `UTF8` to `ANSI`, try the following function:

```
// change encoding from UTF8 to ANSI
char* change_encoding_from_UTF8_to_ANSI(char* szU8)
{ 
    int wcsLen = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, NULL, szU8, strlen(szU8), NULL, 0);
    wchar_t* wszString = new wchar_t[wcsLen + 1];
    ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, NULL, szU8, strlen(szU8), wszString, wcsLen);
    wszString[wcsLen] = '\0';

    int ansiLen = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, NULL, wszString, wcslen(wszString), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    char* szAnsi = new char[ansiLen + 1];
    ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, NULL, wszString, wcslen(wszString), szAnsi, ansiLen, NULL, NULL);
    szAnsi[ansiLen] = '\0';

    delete []wszString;
    return szAnsi;
}
```

Comment: memory leak on wszString

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help - the function above works great. Had I known there was a word- ANSI - for what I was after that would have helped! Warning about MFC also taken on board.

Answer (score 1):

Utf8 has a 1-to-1 mapping with Ascii characters so if you are receiving Ascii characters as utf8 ones, AFAIK you can directly read them as Ascii. If you have non-Ascii chars then there's no way you can express them in Ascii (any byte > 0x80)